# HTML-Javascript Input-Calculation-Output

Tags: javascript, html

I need just want to add some textboxes/form to input data from a user through HTML and take them into variables in a script that will run a calculation and then output the answer to the calculation. I have some code but its not working properly. It seems that when the submit button is clicked, the function isn't called. Any help would be great: here's the code.

```
<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  Initial Displacement: <input type="number" name="x"><br>
  Initial Velocity: <input type="number" name="v"><br>
  Acceleration: <input type="number" name="a"><br>
  Time Passed: <input type="number" name="t"><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<script>
function calc()
{

var b=document.getElementById("frm1");
document.write(b.element[0].value+b.element[1].value*b.element[2].value+(1/2)*b.element[3].value*b.element[2].value*b.element[2].value);
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zytyf16q/#&togetherjs=qABKDyLpK2

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Please paste the code into your question rather than linking a screenshot

Comment: Please use [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [http://codepen.io/](http://codepen.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistype in your code on the submit button. Your submit button should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  Initial Displacement:
  <input type="number" id="x" name="x">
  <br> Initial Velocity:
  <input type="number" id="v" name="v">
  <br> Acceleration:
  <input type="number" id="a" name="a">
  <br> Time Passed:
  <input type="number" id="t" name="t">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calc('x','v','a','t')"     value="Submit">
  </body>
  <script>
  function calc(x, v, a, t) {
   var Displace = parseInt(document.getElementById(x).value)
   var Velocity = parseInt(document.getElementById(v).value)
   var Acceleration = parseInt(document.getElementById(a).value)
   var Time = parseInt(document.getElementById(t).value)
   var calculations = Displace + (Velocity * Acceleration) + ((1 / 2) * Time * Acceleration * Time);
   alert(calculations)
  }

 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: Made that fix but it still doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/zytyf16q/#&togetherjs=qABKDyLpK2

Comment: Well, it works now (sort of). It seems like to be adding them as you would append a string. for example: if displacement =5 and everything else is 0 you get 500    --------        if displacement is 5 velocity is 1 and time is 1 you get 510   --------   so it's like the 5 is the displacement the 1 is the v*t and the 0 is (1/2)at^(2)------- also var calculation should look like------->  var calculations = Displace+Velocity*Time+(1/2)*Time*Acceleration*Time;

Comment: @Zach Fixed the problem. It is working like it should. Edited post.

Answer (score 1):

I added `id`'s to the inputs, and then used `document.getElementById` to select them and save them to a variable with their respective name. Then I carried out the calculation.

```html
<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  Initial Displacement: <input type="number" name="x" id="x"><br>
  Initial Velocity: <input type="number" name="v" id="v"><br>
  Acceleration: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
  Time Passed: <input type="number" name="t" id="t"><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<script>
function calc()
{
var x = document.getElementById('x').value
var v = document.getElementById('v').value
var a = document.getElementById('a').value
var t = document.getElementById('t').value
document.write(x+v*a+(1/2)*t*a*a);
}
</script>
```

Comment: it looks like this code has the same problem as i mentioned in my above comment

Comment: Ok. The first set of code didn't work, but this one worked fine for me

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but it works in this jsFiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/17dymkbc/